# Use jinja2 from within html to control which javascript to load depending on an environment variable

Tags: jinja2

I have an main.html file that loads a javascript file depending on a mode (development or production)

```
cat main.html
...
{% block javascript %}
  <!-- for development -->
  <script type="module" src="main1.js"></script>

  <!-- for production -->
  <script type="module" src="main2.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Currently I go back and forth to manually:

- enable main1.js and disable main2.js, for development
- disable main1.js and enable main2.js, for production

I want to control this automatically via jinja2 by having an `if` statement to control which js file to load, depending on the environment variable.
The following code works, but I want to control with an environment variable (instead of the python variable *current_user.role*)

```
{% block javascript %}
  {% if (current_user.role == "admin") %}
    <!-- for development -->
    <script type="module" src="main1.js"></script>
  {% else %}
    <!-- for production -->
    <script type="module" src="main2.js"></script>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that this can be done with:

```
cat main.py
...
from flask import render_template, session
...
@bp.route('/')
def main_page():
...
    session['mode'] = 'development'

    return render_template('main.html', mode=session['development'])
```

```
cat templates/main.html
...
{% block body1 %}
  {% if mode == "development" %}
    <!-- for development -->
    <script type="module" src="main1.js"></script>
  {% else %}
    <!-- for production -->
    <script type="module" src="main2.js"></script>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```